# Auto-chose platform (or other) condition in tox sections

Tags: python, continuous-integration, automated-tests, tox

I want to specifically run a certain tox section which then auto-decides on the specific platform.
The example code-snippet below works fine if I just ran `tox -e ALL`. Then the platform condition nicely sects out the correct platform.

However, I want to **only** adress and run a specific section like for instance something like `tox -e other` (not `tox -e other-win, other-linux`) and then have `tox` auto-chosing the corresponding platform (or any other) condition.

I don't know if this way of setting up conditions in `tox` is not possible, or if I'm missing something.

```
[tox]
skipsdist = true

[testenv:systest-{win, linux}]
platform =
    linux: linux
    win: win|msys

whitelist_externals = 
    win: cmd
    linux: sh

commands =
    win: cmd /r echo {env:OS}
    linux: sh -c echo {env:OS}

[testenv:other-{win, linux}]
platform =
    linux: linux
    win: win|msys

whitelist_externals = 
    win: cmd
    linux: sh

commands =
    win: cmd /r echo {env:OS}
    linux: sh -c echo {env:OS}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the [`tox-factor` plugin](https://pypi.org/project/tox-factor/) a try.

For example:

`tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist =
    alpha-{redmond,tux}
    bravo-{redmond,tux}
requires =
    tox-factor
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
commands =
    python -c 'import sys; print("platform", sys.platform)'
platform =
    redmond: win32
    tux: linux
```

This gives the following four environments:

```
$ tox --listenvs
alpha-redmond
alpha-tux
bravo-redmond
bravo-tux
```

That can be selected according to the factors:

```
$ tox --listenvs --factor tux
alpha-tux
bravo-tux
$ tox --listenvs --factor alpha
alpha-redmond
alpha-tux
```

And then run like this (for example on a Linux platform):

```
$ tox --factor bravo
bravo-tux run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='1770792708'
bravo-tux run-test: commands[0] | python -c 'import sys; print("platform", sys.platform)'
platform linux
________________________________________________ summary ________________________________________________
SKIPPED:  bravo-redmond: platform mismatch ('linux' does not match 'win32')
  bravo-tux: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

**References**:

- https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1338
- https://pypi.org/project/tox-factor/

Comment: Yes, that's it. Works superb. Thanks!